# Is there precedence to listing out tokens in a parser.mly file?

Tags: parsing, ocaml, ocamllex, ocamlyacc

Like if I have some tokens listed at the beginning of my parser like so

```
%{
open Ast
%}

%token SEMI LPAREN RPAREN LBRACE RBRACE COMMA PLUS MINUS TIMES DIVIDE ASSIGN
%token NOT EQ NEQ LT LEQ GT GEQ AND OR
%token RETURN IF ELSE FOR WHILE INT BOOL FLOAT VOID
%token <int> LITERAL
%token <bool> BLIT
%token <string> ID FLIT
%token EOF
```

Is there any type of precedence associated with this? Or is this just a listing of the tokens with no particular importance to order?

Comment: It's just a list of tokens with no implied ordering. Many of us put them in alphabetical order for convenience.

Comment: Precedence declarations: http://gallium.inria.fr/~fpottier/menhir/manual.html#sec10